# How to count commented lines in a JS source using Python?

Tags: python, lines

I'm writing a little tool in Python to count source code lines, comments lines and blank/empty lines.

Actually I'm able to count all lines and all empty but I'm having trouble to count comment ones, can someone help me? I'm new to this lang.

```
def file_len(pFile):
    filled,blanks = 0
    for line in open(pFile).readlines():
        if line.strip():
            filled += 1
        if not line.strip():
            blanks += 1
    return filled, blanks


url = 'C:/blablablabla/littlesource.js'
f = open(url, 'r')
k = f.read()
print(k)

source_properties = file_len(url)
print('Code: ',source_properties[0],'Empty: ',source_properties[1])
f.close()
```

For "code" I  actually means all source that is not blank lines, so I can't do "Comment lines = (All lines) - (Source code lines) - (Blank/empty lines)" as suggested by jkdev...

Comment: Comment lines = (All lines) - (Source code lines) - (Blank/empty lines)

Comment: Maybe "this is a string".startswith('this')  helps you. Afer stripping the beginning spaces you could check for '//'. Ofcourse you need to check for a possible "end tag" like '/*...*/' --. multiline support

Comment: I would suggest to use a regex for identifiing comments 
Maybe this link will help you 
http://blog.ostermiller.org/find-comment

Answer (score 0):

Problem is sometimes the code has // but its not a comment.

for example:

```
url = "http://helloworld/"
```

if I search for `//` I'd incorrectly count this line.
So first thing I remove all strings from my code

```
code_without_strings = re.sub("""("[^"]+"|'[^']+')""", "", code)
```

After that I find all `//` (only once per line) and count their number

```
 len(re.findall("(//.*(\n|$))", code_without_strings))
```

If you also want to consider `/* */` it might get a bit more complicated.

```
 len(re.findall("(/\*.*?\*/", code_without_strings, flags=re.S))
```

but then you have to account for the case where `//` is located inside `/* */` block. which you can do by first counting number of multiline comments, then delete them (same as what we did with strings) then count the single lined comments